# Are there any shops in hostile zones?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In *FTL: Faster Than Light*, each sector is labeled as either **Civilian**, **[Species] Controlled**, or **Nebula**. Each of these sectors has a corresponding color that determines whether or not they are Friendly, Hostile, or a Nebula.

I've found shops in Friendly sectors, I've found shops in Nebulas. I can't recall ever seeing a shop in a Hostile sector. I'm desperately low on fuel, and in dire need of a shop. The problem I'm facing is that I'm stuck going through three hostile sectors in a row.

**Can I find a shop in a Hostile sector?**

Comment: Some Nebula are Slug controlled too. FYI. So they count as [Species] controlled AND nebula.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. Each sector generates with a different possible number of stores, like so:

- **Civilian sectors** (Civilian/Engi/Zoltan) each have **2-3 stores**.
- **Hostile sectors** (Pirate/Rock/Rebel/Mantis) each have **1-2 stores**.
- **Nebula sectors** (Slug/Uncharted) each have **1-2 stores**.
- **The Last Stand** has **one store** and you probably won't have time to find it.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence here, but I recall having a store in the final sector. Are they explicitly not there? Was it more likely an event that created a store on the spot?

Comment: @rsegal yes the final sector has stores, I've only ever seen 1 there at a time, most of the time none, but then again I don't check everything.

Comment: I didn't actually see anything specific about the final sector, so perhaps it has one or two like the rest. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The final sector works basically the same as every other sector, and `<event name="STORE" min="1" max="1"/>` is in its definition. Looks not just possible, but mandatory.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Oh, cool, thanks for editing that in.

Comment: Note that there may be only 1 store in the Last Stand, but there are repair nodes where you get repaired (not always fully) and resupplied for free.

Answer (score 8):

Yes absolutely. There are stores in hostile zones. I find them all the time, and the next time I do, I'll screenshot it.

[image]

In addition, there are also stores in the final sector.

[image]

Comment: Although not absolutely necessary, it would be nice if you cropped the images so only the relevant information is shown. In these cases,  only the beacon map is necessary.